# DynamoDB Json Formatting w/ Node.js with Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I've got an issue here with formatting my json and I can't quite figure out how to do it.  when I run this code via Lambda:

```
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
body = await dynamo.scan({ TableName: "MyTutorials" }).promise();
body = JSON.stringify(body);
```

It returns as json string that looks like this:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "published": false,
            "description": "This is an orange.",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "published": true,
            "description": "this is an apple",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Apple"
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2
}
```

Thats great and all, but for my React app I need something cleaner that looks like this:

```
[
        {
            "published": false,
            "description": "This is an orange.",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "published": true,
            "description": "this is an apple",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Apple"
        }
    ]
```

Bascially, I need just the straight-up array in the json and not wrapped with all the other stuff like "Items" and "Count."  Any ideas on how to make that call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return the items of body:

```
body = JSON.stringify(body.Items);
```